# How many Thread JVM Run parallel of our main thread and when Garbage Collection get started

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I am new for java please clear my this more doubt.I know that Garbage collection also run but when garbage collection get started.Is it started when we run our program? Some one help me.I see that how many thread parallel by jconsole command.But I want to know about Garbage collection Thread when it get started.

Comment: I am just starting learning java please ignore if you thing this is stupid question.I want to become a professional in java.That is why I want to know deeply all concept.

Comment: Actually I want to know that how to show how many thread are running in virtual Machine and I got That is jconsole command which give all information about memory,thread,Classes and other more thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: **No specific number can be quoted.**

It depends on JVM version, garbage collection algorithm used, specific framework thread(swing,jmx), etc.

Normally you will always see Finalizer Thread(executes finalize method), Signal Dispatcher(to handle signals ctrl+c), Reference Handler.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is started when the Java Virtual Machine is run, since the garbage collector is one of the many possible processes part of it. And that Java Virtual Machine will ALSO run one or more of your applications.